# Optimal way of reading files created by kernel in constant state of change?

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I am looking to for a way to read files that are created by the kernel which are on a constant state of change. On the beaglebone, getting the values of say the analog input is a matter of reading from a file, lets call it `ain_value`. The recommended way of getting this value is using the `cat` command. However, I would like to be able to read from the file using C. My current way of handling this seems to have some flaws. There are some sync issues if I try to read the file in anything less than a one second loop. Using `watch --interval=0.5 'cat ain_value' I can get consistent values, when using the following code I get that the file cannot be opened. Is there a way to sync with the OS and make the following code more dependable?

```
int AIN_value(char AIN) {
    char line[10] = {0};
    char BUFFER[35];

    snprintf(BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER), "%s%c", AIN_FILE, AIN);
    FILE *fp;
    fp  = fopen(BUFFER, "r");
        if(fp == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: could not open %s\n", BUFFER);
        }

    printf("\n"); // Temporary fix until we know how to sync file reads.
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) == NULL) {
        printf("ERORR: could not read from %s\n", BUFFER);
    }

    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);
    return(atoi(line));
}
```

A side note is that when using the `printf("\n"); // Temporary fix until we know how to sync file reads.` line I can get accurate file reads, however if I remove this line I get wrong values.

Comment: `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';` ?? `strlen()` itself need tun-terminated array you logic here is not correct. `fgets()` returns nul-terminated array

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan using this code removes the newline character I was seeing when printing the line. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: What is the full path to this file? Is it a `/dev/` or `/proc/` file? If so, it's not a real file - it's either a direct device interface, or a kernel data interface.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen `/sys/devices/ocp.2/helper.14/AIN` - specific to the beaglebone

Comment: @arynhard then remove `\n` nut not last check, What I mean to say `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';` do nothing it is writing `\0` over `\0`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I see. Thank you. I will modify it accodingly

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan actually, what he has is correct - `strlen(line)` is the length of the string, not including the `\0`, so `line[strlen(line)]` is actually where the `\0` is.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The file can be opened in any loop greater than or equal to 1 second. I would like quicker reads. I believe I mentioned that I get this error only when using a loop under 1 sec.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You always find mistakes in my answer `ಠ_ಠ`

Comment: @arynhard You were correct Read @ Drew's comment to me

Answer (score 0):

If reading the `/sys/devices/ocp.2/helper.14/AIN` pseudo file yields wrong data, the kernel code generating that data is at fault. Other than having this code corrected, you might look whether there's a better API for reading the analog input etc. available.